# how to get userid who made the action from messages sent to teams using incoming webhooks

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am sending Approve and Reject messages to Teams using incoming webhooks. Using API gateway as the target URL. How do i get the user info who made the request or how do i secure this.

sending the action card from python script to teams